# Dynamically Increase the text count on click in BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter

I have Like Button In Layout and set the text "like 0" , i Have Set in Base Adapter , When I click on Like Buttton, the text will increase without refresh the whole Activity Like in facebook app , I am stuck on three days , i have read and implements almost every answer of stackoverflow , but not get the solution. I hope i will get the answer. Here is My Base Adapter <------->

```
public class FeedAdaptorView   extends BaseAdapter{

  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;

        HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String UserID;
     public FeedAdaptorView(Context context,
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist, String uSERid2) {
            this.context = context;
            data = arraylist;

        }
        public class ViewHolder {
            TextView name,time,status,likecount;
            ImageView userimage,postimage;
            Button like,comment,share;

        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {


              if(convertView==null){
                  LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                  convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);
                  holder=new ViewHolder();
                  pos=getItemViewType(position);
                  holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

                  holder.status=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
                  holder.userimage=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
                  holder.postimage=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);
                  holder.like=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.like);
                  holder.comment=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
                  holder.pos=position;

                  convertView.setTag(holder);
              }
              else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
              holder.like.setTag(pos);
         /*   inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            holder.comment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);
            }
        });         .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);*/

       holder.comment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);
            }
        });
       holder.postimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);
            }
        });
       holder.like.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    Toast.makeText(context, "You Liked The Post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           holder.like.setText("Like"+"4");

           notifyDataSetChanged();
    // here i am calling the web services for like button update
   new likepost().execute();

            }
        });
```

<--------------------------------->

```
webservice callin method
class likepost extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
        {
            int flag=0;
         @Override
         protected void onPreExecute()
         {
          super.onPreExecute();
          // Create a progressdialog
          mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
          // Set progressdialog message
          mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
          mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
          mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
          // Show progressdialog
          mProgressDialog.show();
         }

         @Override
         protected Void doInBackground(Void... args0) {
          List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


                   String Status="1";
          String ID=feedid;

          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserID",UserID));
          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FeedId",ID));
          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("like_status",Status));

          JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(AppControllerClass.FeedLike,"POST", params);
          Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

          try{
           if(json!=null)
           {
             String status=json.getString("status");
             if(status.equals("Success"))
             {
              flag=1;
             // Toast.makeText(context, "You Liked The Post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
             else
             {
             flag=2;
             //Toast.makeText(context, "Check The Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
             }
           }
           else{
            flag=2;
           }

          }
          catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
          }


          return null;
         }
         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(Void args) 
         {
          mProgressDialog.dismiss();
          if(flag==1)
          {
           Toast.makeText(context, "You Liked The Post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }
          else if (flag==2) 
          {
           Toast.makeText(context, "Check The Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
          } 



         }
```

Comment: whether you are getting count in service call?

Comment: i updated , on fregment i getting the whole list view , which will have "like" and in base adapter , on click like button  i call the service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Dynamically Increase the text count on click in BaseAdapter

Do it as using `getTag/setTag`:

```
@Override
 public void onClick(View c) {
    int count=0; 
    if(v.getTag()==null)
        count=0;
    else{
      count=Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
    }
    count++;
    ((TextView)v).setText("Like"+count);
    v.setTag(count);
 }
```

Comment: yes i got it..i edit some changes with your code  ,,thankx alot .. i h

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
@Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }
```

instead of

```
@Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: i have goth the value of count
  String pos=data.get(position).get("TempLike");...but when set into holder.like..it will not updated

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time answering questions on StackOverflow and I hope that my answer is able to help you solve your problem.

PROBLEM :

```
 holder.like.setText("Like"+"4");

 notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The problem is here. You have manually set it to setText("Like"+"4"). In BaseAdapter's notifyDataSetChanged() function, it refers to an ADAPTER of information.

In your case, it will be the reference of resulttp. It is referencing to the data ArrayList you have passed in. And when you call notifyDataSetChanged(), it will refer back to the resulttp and display WHAT is in the ArrayList.

SOLUTION :

1) Remove this line

```
holder.like.setText("Like"+"4");
```

2) Add in a new function called update() in your BaseAdapter class

```
public void updateAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newData)
{

     this.data.clear();
     this.data = data;
     notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

3) On your like button / image onClickListener, call the function updateAdapter() and pass in an UPDATED ArrayList.

It should be alright already. Good Luck!